# How to implement a horizontal table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a horizontal table view in swift with the following functionalities:

- Images listed in a horizontal manner
- Horizontal scrolling left and right

See wireframe attached.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried digging into UICollectionView to implement this.

[image]

Comment: Tableviews are vertical. If you want that functionality, you'll need to utilize UICollectionView or a UIScrollView.

Comment: You can also think about using a UIPageController: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

### - SwiftUI

This question is asked a lot and there are so many answers out there for using `CollectionView`. But in **SwiftUI** you can use a horizontal `ScrollView` containing a Horizontal `Stack` like this:

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 80, alignment: .center)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Categories")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) { Text("More") }
            }.padding(16)
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0...15, id: \.self) { _ in
                        CardView()
                    }
                }.padding(16)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### - Result

[image: Result]

**Note that** you can use this inside a `UITableViewCell` **later this month** when **SwiftUI** officially released by Apple.

Comment: The question does not appear to be asking for a SwiftUI solution.

Comment: Asking for a solution with Swift and SwiftUI is written in Swift. And it’s usable in TableView. Maybe helps. @rmaddy

Comment: I don’t think I support Swift UI. I’m on v10